# SQL type field not updating list in joomla module

Tags: php, joomla

I have created and installed one joomla module where i have added one sql type parameter field and fetching data from database. So Database table's Data gradually updated and added, but data not updated in list in module.

Please help how can update list without re-installing module.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to update the xml file..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cache issue, try clearing cache or admin cache.  Does this solve the issue?

Joomla enables caching by default on all extensions, so you would have to explicitly disable it in the module configuration or code, depending on your needs.